# How to avoid repeat the same lines on CSS?

Tags: css

I do not want to repeat the same property all the time on my `CSS`.

In my case, I have three media queries in which I change the property of `padding` of a specific element and after I need to put it as the beginning:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px){
     ul > a{
         padding-top: 20px;
         padding-bottom: 20px;
     }
}

@media (max-width: 750px){
     ul > a{
         padding-top: 16px;
         padding-bottom: 16px;
     }
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
     ul > a{
         padding-top: 20px;
         padding-bottom: 20px;
     }
}
```

As you can see, I have to put the same code on the first and on the third one media query and I would like to reduce the amount of lines of my `CSS`.

I would like to wrap these lines into a variable or something similar:

```
ul > a{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

and use them in the whole `CSS` each time I need it.

I found that there is an [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) to create variables on `CSS` but that it has not been stabilized yet and it does not have a full browser support.

Thus, is there a method to use more than one line on `CSS` without repeating them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at scss: http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Use a CSS preprocessor. CSS is filled with duplication, but you can allow the duplicated code to be generated for you.

Comment: Yes, Carcigenicate is right you might want to consider using a CSS preprocessor if your not already.  You could create a mixin to avoid repeating CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Just define the common rule without a media query and then use media queries to override it as necessary, like so:

```
ul a{
    padding:20px 0;
}
@media (max-width:750px){
    ul a{
        padding:16px 0;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, add `min-width` to your media queries and create a new one to define all the common rules in, like so:

```
@media (max-width:500px),(min-width:751px) and (max-width:1000px){
    ul a{
        padding:20px 0;
    }
}
@media (min-width:501px) and (max-width:750px){
    ul a{
        padding:16px 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one query with `min` and `max` width [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/671/), also only `li` element can be direct child of `ul` element (i used `color` instead of `margin` form demo)

```css
ul a {
  color: blue;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 750px) {
  ul a {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
</ul>
```